# Permission issue for git in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I am integrating jenkins and Git Lab

My git lab permission is set as Internal
  In Jenkins SCM sections i mentioned my git url with credential and added the 
  crdential in configure section too
  But it throws error
    Failed to connect to repository : 
     Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h https://xxx.git HEAD" returned status              code 128:
    stdout:
    stderr: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https:xxx.git/'
      Please give me a resolution.I want the git permission to be internal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjenkins%5D+%5Bgit%5D+ls-remote+Access+denied

Answer (score 3):

Please check [Gitlab with Jenkins](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/38910), you can follow the steps which are mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not the same but for me the Global API token "type" didn't work for me (same error as you) so for me work Create new credentials of type **"username & password"**, in username put the Access token name of your credential in gitlab, and in password the token.